# Which version of Java does SBT use?

Tags: scala, sbt

How to find out, which version of JDK SBT uses?

My laptop has both JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 installed, so I was just wondering.

Comment: Just check your SBT launcher script and what java-home (and javaHome) is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just run sbt console and you'll get something like this:

Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

Which shows you the version of Java being used.

Cheers

JC

Comment: This doesn't seem to be showing anymore for me with sbt 0.13.7. It may have been removed even earlier than this build. The comment below using eval is working though, that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed. I'd also note that if people don't know what version of the JVM they're working with in a given context, then they probably shouldn't be asking questions like this.  Is the question about which version of Java SBT is using, or rather which version do you want it to be using.  If it's the latter, then the second answer below is actually more correct.

Comment: Using `console` needs to have the project compilable and it might not be since a wrong jdk is used.

Answer (score 83):

You can use `eval` at the sbt prompt with the appropriate system properties:

```
> eval System.getProperty("java.version")
[info] ans: String = 1.7.0_45
> eval System.getProperty("java.home")
[info] ans: String = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

(The other answers are fine too, this is just another method.)

Answer (score 8):

`sbt -v` is another way:

```
# sbt -v
[process_args] java_version = '1.7.0_121'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar

[info] Loading project definition from /root/.sbt/0.13/staging/a6d8e5030b69785a9763/build/project
[info] Set current project to xx (in build file:/build/)
>
```

Comment: Ah.. where is it stored :) ??? sbt uses 1.7 java, I want to switch this miracle to use 1.8

Answer (score 7):

It's actually easy.

Find the command line of SBT (`` cat `which sbt` ``) and see which Java it is.

For example, my SBT command line begins with:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xmx512M
```

And `/usr/bin/java -version` tells the Java version, in my case it is 1.7.

Comment: You can't really say `/usr/bin/java` will be used, it could be overridden for sbt startup in multiple ways .... isn't this misleading?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file method I created to get that info immediately from the command line (Windows only, but you can do something similar in a shell script):

```
@echo off
setlocal
sbt "eval System.getProperty(\"java.version\")" "eval System.getProperty(\"java.home\")"
@echo on
```